# JavaScript calendar in Drupal (Scheduler module)

Tags: drupal

hi i have installed scheduler module from drupal.org. and i have set all the settings regarding this. now i can set publish and unpublished  date in text box(there is format of date below text box).
i want to use java script calendar so when user click on the text box ,the calendar should open.
how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Drupal you should have JQuery preloaded. You don't necessarily need JQuery to do this but it makes it easier, you'll use JavaScript either way.

With JQuery, simply setup a click listener on the textbox and have it call the whatever function triggers the calendar display like so...

Note: I used a simple ID selector below "#textbox" replace it with whatever way you want to select your textbox input. (eg. if you've given the HTML textbox input element an ID of "textbox" you can use my example)

```
 $(document).ready(function(event) {
  $('#textbox').live('click', function() {
     //call your function here
  });   
});
```